# argument of type is incompatible with parameter of type error

Tags: c++, winapi, text, wchar-t

```
uintptr_t gameModule = (uintptr_t)GetModuleHandle("client.dll");
```

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2664   'HMODULE GetModuleHandleW(LPCWSTR)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'const char [11]' to 'LPCWSTR'

Comment: Wild guess, try `GetModuleHandleA` function.

Comment: Have you defined `UNICODE`? Most WinAPI functions `xyz` are actually macros and map to either `xyzA` (non-`UNICODE`) or `xyzW` (`UNICODE`). You might: 1. Undefine `UNICODE`, 2. call `GetModuleHandleA` directly or load via wide character string `L"client.dll"`.

Comment: You shouldn't cast the return value, by the way, just retain the type `HMODULE` – this keeps you from trouble for the case MS decides changing the type, e. g. to a more complex struct (though, admitted, not too likely...).

Comment: thanks. Best solution

Comment: @aco Do you know of a single incident where the Windows API introduced an ABI break?

Comment: @IInspectable To be honest, actually not. But there's simply no need for, I'd consider it even bad practice that might be ported to other libraries which *might* change ABI.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> uintptr_t gameModule = (uintptr_t)GetModuleHandle("client.dll");
> ```
>
> HMODULE GetModuleHandleW(LPCWSTR)': cannot convert argument 1 from
> 'const char [11]' to 'LPCWSTR'

`"client.dll"` is a `char` string (`const char [11]`).

According to the [Windows API TCHAR model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/conventions-for-function-prototypes), `GetModuleHandle` is a preprocessor macro which is expanded to `GetModuleHandleW` in Unicode builds (the default build mode for Visual Studio C++ projects since VS 2005).

`GetModuleHandleW` requires a `LPCWSTR` string parameter, i.e. a `const wchar_t*`, which is a `wchar-t` string.

So, you have a mismatch in your `GetModuleHandle` call, as you passed a `char` string, but `GetModuleHandle` (which is expanded to `GetModuleHandleW`) requires a `wchar_t` string (`LPCWSTR`).

You can fix this error passing `L"client.dll"` instead of `"client.dll"`; in fact, `L"client.dll"` (note the **L** prefix) is a `wchar_t` string:

```
// Pass L"client.dll" instead of "client.dll"
uintptr_t gameModule = (uintptr_t)GetModuleHandle(L"client.dll");
```

---

Another option would be *explicitly* invoking the "ANSI" function `GetModuleHandleA`:

```
// Explicitly call GetModuleHandleA
uintptr_t gameModule = (uintptr_t)GetModuleHandleA("client.dll");
```

but I would stick with Unicode APIs.

You could even totally embrace the TCHAR model, and decorate your string literal with `_T()` or `TEXT()`, e.g.:

```
uintptr_t gameModule = (uintptr_t)GetModuleHandle(_T("client.dll"));
```

That would work in both ANSI and UNICODE builds.

Comment: Technically, since `GetModuleHandle()` is a Win32 API macro, you *should* use the Win32 API's [`TEXT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/nf-winnt-text) macro instead of the C library's `_T()` macro: `GetModuleHandle(TEXT("client.dll"))`. But, since `_T()` and `TEXT()` are *typically* interchangable (as `UNICODE`[Win32] and `_UNICODE`[C] are typically (un)defined together), the end result is the same, though I would not suggest crossing API boundaries like this.

Comment: I have always used `_T()` as it’s less typing and less verbose. From a **practical** perspective, they are interchangeable and are both valid.